# react-hooks-helper, TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so what I'm trying to do right now implementing a multi-step form with the help of react-hooks-helper, lets just get into the case, I'm trying to give onChange property to my Dropdown so when the value has been selected it will be sent to my formData, it's working wonderfully on text field but not the dropdown that semantic-ui has, I've tried several components like autocomplete material-ui/lab,react-select-search etc. but it's still giving me the error.

so here's my code:  ***Form.js***

```
    import { Dropdown } from "semantic-ui-react";
    import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";
    import { useForm } from "react-hooks-helper";

const form = () => {
        const defaultData = {
              branch: "",
              branchName: "",
        };
        const [formData, setForm] = useForm(defaultData);
        const {branch, branchName} = formData;
        
              const options = [
            { key: 1, text: "branch A", value: "A" },
            { key: 2, text: "branch B", value: "B" },
            { key: 3, text: "branch C", value: "C" },
              ];
            return (
            <div>
           <TextField
           label="Branch Name"
           name="branchName"
           value={branchName}
           onChange={setForm}
           />
            <Dropdown
                name="branch"
                options={options}
                placeholder="Choose Branch"
                value={branch}
                onChange={(e, value) =>
                  setForm({
                    branch: value,
                  })
                }
              />
            </div>)
        }
export default form;
```

Comment: Have you tried using `onChange={setForm}` for the Dropdown? The handler has access to the element via the event so it can read its `name`; my guess is by calling `setForm` as if it's a standard state setter, you're removing the point of the helper and breaking its code?

Comment: @ChrisG yes, but it gives me different type of error, it says Cannot read property 'split' of undefined